# jquery onchange event on page reloads does not works

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to disable other dropdown based on the dropdown selected.
Below is the code for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery('select').change(function() {
  if(jQuery(this).val() == "A"){
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1'))
          .attr('disabled','disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1'))
         .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1'))
         .removeAttr('disabled');
  } else if(jQuery(this).val() == "R"){
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1'))
        .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1'))
         .attr('disabled','disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1'))
        .attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1'))
       .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1'))
       .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1'))
      .removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 })
})
</script>
```

So after page reloads the fields which are disable are enable again, but the selection is there to disable those fields.

Please help!!

Thanks
Sanket

Comment: Would you mind to edit your post, so the horizontal scrollbar will disappear?

Comment: is this good now

Comment: @reporter You think this looks much better?

Comment: Did you try `$('#select').val('[Default value]').trigger('change');` after loading document?

Comment: what it will do basically...can you please provide an example or some link

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen a little better.

Comment: side note: you should be using .prop instead of .attr for the "disabled" option - this was changed years ago in jQuery 1.6 http://api.jquery.com/attr/ - _To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method._

Comment: @reporter I admire if I find this easier since this made me drop the question and move on.

Comment: is it same as onchange event?

Comment: here we are using jquery 1.3 so prop is not working.

Comment: "So after page reloads the fields which are disable are enable again". This is normal behaviour for a web page, as they are stateless. "but the selection is there to disable those fields." You mean the "disabled" option is still selected? If so, is there some server-side framework (or other persistence) being used to keep the selected value?

Comment: Yes the server side validation is there to still keep those values. Actually these parts are part of a filter and when we select the filter and click on appply it gets the data from db based on the filters selected, so after that the dropdown is still selected which should disable those other fields.

Comment: Is there any way when the page refresh it will detect if the value is there in that dropdown, so that i can disable those fields

Comment: "which should disable those other fields". No because that disabling is done on the client, and the whole page is destroyed (because it's stateless, other than those aspects which are specifically persisted by a server-side framework). So at page load you need to check the value of the dropdown, same as you do when the dropdown is changed..

Comment: Exactly that i need to do...to check the value in the dropdown when the page reloads.Can you please tell me on how to do that

Comment: @Sanky did any of the answers help you? If so please consider upvoting and/or marking the best answer as accepted - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should write your conditions into page_load function also to get the effects on page refresh:

```
  $(document).on("pageload",function(){
      //add here logic related to get currently selected value from dropdown and make 
     other tags disable as per your requirement
  });
```

Let me know if you face any issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

At page load you need to check the value of the dropdown, same as you do when the dropdown is changed.

This is because although your server-side code persists the selected value of the dropdown, it does not persist the disabled states of the controls which you had set on the client-side. Web pages are inherently stateless and any changes you don't explicitly persist will be destroyed when the page is refreshed.

You can easily re-use your existing code to do this:

```
jQuery(function() {
 setEnabledDisabled(jQuery('select').val()); //runs at page load

 jQuery('select').change(function() {
   setEnabledDisabled(jQuery(this).val());
 });

 //re-usable function to implement the logic
 function setEnabledDisabled(val);
  if(val == "A"){
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1'))
          .attr('disabled','disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1'))
         .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1'))
         .removeAttr('disabled');
  } else if(val == "R"){
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1'))
        .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1'))
         .attr('disabled','disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1'))
        .attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1'))
       .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1'))
       .removeAttr('disabled');
   jQuery(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1'))
      .removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 }
});
```

P.S. As a side note I would strongly suggest upgrading your jQuery version - 1.3 is over 8 years old at the time of writing (released 2009). There have been many bug fixes and enhancements since then, plus changes to support newer browsers and functionality, which you may want to take advantage of. 1.12.4 is the newest version of the 1.x branch, released in May 2016. If you no longer need to support older versions of IE, you can move to the 2.x branch which will result in a smaller download, but without introducing compatibility issues. 3.x makes some breaking changes and would require more thorough testing.

Answer (score 0):

Do this - On  Pageload i.e. on Document Ready ,  the function run_your_rules($val) will be called with whatever is the selection on default

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $this = $('select');
  var $val=$this.val();
  run_your_rules($val);

  $this.on('change',function(e) {
        run_your_rules($(this).val());
  });

  function run_your_rules($val){
    if($val==="A"){
        console.log("disable A");
    }else if($val==="B"){
        console.log("disable B");
    }
  }

})
```